# How to get the sales for last quarter and last month when we are in january in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

For example, we have the data of the years 2017, 2018 & 2019. In case I am in January 2019, I want the data of the last quarter and last month.

My query is like this:

```
Select 
    (case
        When month(datecolumn) = month(getdate()) - 1 
           then sales 
           else 0 
     end) as premonthsales,
    (case 
        when datepart(qq, datecolumn) = datepart(qq, getdate()) - 1 
           then sales 
           else 0 
     end) as lq sales 
from 
    t
```

When I am in January 2019, it is showing me the data of both December 2017 and 2018. I want it dynamic like when I am in Jan 2018, it should show only data of Dec 2017 for last month and last quarter (4rth quarter of 2017).

Comment: *"In case I am in january 2019 I want the data of last quarter and last month"* So you want the data for October to December 2018?  December 2018 is already in the last quarter; so saying you want that in addition seems pointless when it's already included. Would be mean, in March '19, you want want Oct18-Dec18 and Feb 19?

Comment: @Larnu I mean to say the filter can be dynamic it might be jan 2019 or march 2019 but I want to calculate sales for it's previous month and previous quarter no matter how many years data are available.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just after the **previous** quarter, just use basic date logic. This is Pseudo-SQL, however:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE DateColumn >= DATEADD(QUARTER(DATEDIFF(QUARTER,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
  AND DateColumn < DATEADD(QUARTER(DATEDIFF(QUARTER,0,GETDATE()),0);
```

For Jan '19, Dec '18 will already be in the previous quarter, so you don't need additional logic.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first day of the previous quarter in SQL Server, use the following code:

```
SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
```

To get the last day of the previous quarter:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

To get the first day of the current quarter:

```
SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

You get all the dates, based on obtained date apply filter on your data to get the correct result.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE DateColumn between start_date and end_date;
```

[Source](http://zarez.net/?p=2484)

Answer (score 0):

You should include `YEAR` as well

```
SELECT 
      (CASE WHEN MONTH(datecolumn) = MONTH (GETDATE()) - 1 AND  YEAR(datecolumn) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS premonthsales ,
      (CASE WHEN DATEPART(qq,datecolumn) = DATEPART(qq,GETDATE()) - 1 AND AND  YEAR(datecolumn) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) AS lq sales 
FROM t
```

Comment: This is not dynamic #Never because if I am in april of 2019 then it will produce wrong results.